# Transform Element to Match Perspective of Tablet Render

Tags: css, canvas, css-transforms

I'm trying to get an element to match the perspective of a render of an iPad however the best I can achieve is this - [iPad with misaligned element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyxZZ.png)

using `transform: rotateX(67.5deg) rotateY(4.3deg) rotateZ(47.3deg) skew(12.4deg, -4deg) translate(-15px, 88px)`

I know that there must be a way of aligning it properly but I just cant seem to get it. 
Is this possible using CSS or would I need to use something like canvas to properly match it up?

This is my Codepen that I'm working on - https://codepen.io/JackT2/pen/oePmpX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible using CSS?

It is definitely possible to do it via CSS only using the method you're suggesting; but, as you have probably noticed already, it is not a very rewarding task.

> Would I need to use something like canvas to properly match it up?

Canvas might be an overkill; however, an SVG shape would do just fine.

---

My suggestion is to open up any image editing software (or find a simple one online which suits your needs) and **grab the coordinates** of the four edges of the screen of the iPad from your picture. The use the **[`polygon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) SVG element** to draw the overlay.

Technically, you could also do this with **pure CSS** and an ordinary `div` element with the CSS property [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) set to the proper coordinates, but an SVG seems more semantic and has a better browser support at the moment.